# Sequelize select from select

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I want join and filter raw query

```
const projects = await sequelize.query('SELECT * FROM projects + SQL MAGIC', {
  model: Projects,
  mapToModel: true,
  type: QueryTypes.SELECT,
});
```

In this query replace projects table with select+magic:

```
const dynamic_where = {id: 1}

const projects = await Projects.findAll(
  where: { ..dynamic_where },
  include: [{ model: Organization }],
)
```

So generated query shall become

```
SELECT fields,... FROM (SELECT * FROM projects + SQL MAGIC) JOIN organization WHERE organization.id = 1;
```

`bind` not suitable because of `dynamic_where` can contain different number of fields.

Comment: What stops you from joining all needed values in `bind` dynamically as well as you did with `where`?

Comment: `query` has no `where` params - so i need write own query generator... cant bind joined model for Organization ... `findAll` cant window.

Comment: maybe https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/sub-queries/, but it generates `join`, not `select from select`

Answer (score 1):

If you need to modify `FROM` part, I think you need to use a little more low level access to Sequelize.

There is a function `queryGenerator.selectQuery` however this takes string as `FROM` table name meaning if I do

```sql
selectQuery('(...SQL MAGIC)', options, Projects)
```

This will generate a query string as

```sql
SELECT ... FROM '(...SQL MAGIC)' ...
```

FROM query is taken as a string value which is not a valid SQL.

So, a little hacky workaround.

```js
const customQuery = selectQuery('FROM_TO_BE_REPLACED', options, Projects)
// Use JS string replace to add dynamic SQL for FROM.
// If it is Postgres, double quotes are added by queryGenerator.
// If MySQL, it would be ``
customQuery.replace('"FROM_TO_BE_REPLACED"', '(...SQL MAGIC)')
```

All in action.

```
const Model = require("sequelize/lib/model");

const parentOptions = {
  where: {
    id: 1,
    key: 'value'
  },
  include: [Organization]
};

// This is required when the inline query has `include` options, this 1 line make sure to serialize the query correctly.
Model._validateIncludedElements.bind(Projects)(parentOptions);

const customQuery = sequelize.getQueryInterface()
                     .queryGenerator
                     .selectQuery('FROM_TO_BE_REPLACED', parentOptions, Projects);

const fromQuery = '(SELECT * FROM SQL MAGIC)';

const projects = await sequelize.query(customQuery.replace('"FROM_TO_BE_REPLACED"', fromQuery), 
  {
    type: QueryTypes.SELECT
  }
);
```